# two search forms on the same page

Tags: functions, customization, search

I have a mobile and a large screen search field. I am trying to load these both on the same page. I am using JointsWP Starter theme.

Here are the functions:

```
function joints_wpsearch($form) {
  $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
  <div class="small-10 columns no-pad">
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="'.esc_attr__('Search the Site','jointstheme').'" />
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 columns no-pad srchBtn">
  </div>
  </form>';
  return $form;
}

function custom_search( $form ) {
  $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform2" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
  <div class="medium-11 small-10 columns no-pad">
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s2" placeholder="'.esc_attr__('Search the Site','jointstheme').'" />
  </div>
  <div class="medium-1 small-2 columns no-pad">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="srchBtn2" value="" />
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>';
  return $form;
}
```

Here are my hooks:

```
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'joints_wpsearch' );

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'custom_search' );
```

Here is what I am putting in the HTML file to call them:

```
<?php get_search_form('custom_search'); ?>

<?php get_search_form('joints_wpsearch'); ?>
```

But it loads the custom_search form for both of them. What am I doing wrong. Is this something I can even do. I am still learning WordPress but I thought this was something I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_search_form` function doesn't work like that. The parameter that is accepted only specifies if the `HTML` content is being returned or outputted directly. So this parameter should be a boolean. It still works in your case because PHP simply evaluates the string that you are passing as true considering that it is not an empty string, 0, `null` etc. It would still work if you would pass 'null' as a string and not `null`the keyword :)

In case you are not willing to write your own basic `get_search_form` implementation (which is not difficult at all if you [look in the source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/general-template.php#L196) - the `locate_template` function does all the magic so just pass a variable to your function with the template name and use that when calling the `locate_template` function) you can do something like setting a global variable right before calling the `get_search_form` with what HTML you would like to use.

Then, when hooking to the `get_search_form` filter, simply check what that global variable was set to and return the appropriate `HTML` content. Internally WordPress uses a lot of global variables so you would just follow the broken, bad practice that it is already in place I suppose (in case you have a hard time using global variables).

Comment: Thank you so much. I wrote my own get_search_form function and it worked perfectly. But you showed me something new that can be used far beyond even the search. I really appreciate it.